# Store a value in a cell based on what has been selected in the drop down list

Tags: excel

as the title suggests. I have a drop down list in E4, which has some names. In cell M29 there is an action that needs to be inputted regarding that name. So if the user chooses Name "A" for example and he input a value in M29, That value needs to be associated for the name in E4 and stay stored.

if another name is chosen in E4, the value of M29 needs to be cleared and the same process will be repeated for that name and so on until each name has its corresponding action.

is this even possible in excel? I dont mind using VBA for this.

Thanks.

I tried a direct approach were I simply put a drop down list in M29 but whatever name you choose in E4 the value of M29 will be the same.

Comment: *I dont mind using VBA for this* Welcome to SO. No problem at using VBA at all. Start coding, post the code you've developed, what errors are you getting and example of input and expected output.